# Magento layered navigation configurable product out of stock

Tags: magento, navigation, stock, configurable, layered

I have 2 configurable products with size variations, both have three sizes, small, medium and large.

In the first product, the simple product for the small size is out of stock.

If i set in the layered navigation to filter by small size, this product still shows in my product list but when i navigate into product page, the size is not displayed.

There is any way to not show this product in the product list?

Comment: did you figured it out ? I have same issue

Answer (score 0):

Is it not working for you ? Please check this out.
https://digicloud.zendesk.com/entries/22144483-Show-hide-out-of-stock-products-in-Magento